# Show THREE.Group() if radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

What I want to do is showing a group if a certain radio button is checked.
How can I achieve this?

```
 <input id="option1" type="radio" name="options" value="" checked="checked"/>
 <input id="option2" type="radio" name="options" value="" />
```

**Load "groupA" if radio-button "option1" is checked**

```
var groupA = new THREE.Group();

  // Basis
   loader.load('/models/model1.js', function(geometry){
       var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       loadJson(mesh);
   });
    function loadJson(mesh){
        groupA.add(mesh);
    }


  // Basis
   loader.load('/models/model2.js', function(geometry){
       var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       loadJson(mesh);
   });
    function loadJson(mesh){
        groupA.add(mesh);
    }

scene.add( groupA );
```

**Load "groupB" if radio-button "option2" is checked**

```
var groupB = new THREE.Group();

  // Basis
   loader.load('/models/model1.js', function(geometry){
       var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       loadJson(mesh);
   });
    function loadJson(mesh){
        group.add(mesh);
    }


  // Basis
   loader.load('/models/model2.js', function(geometry){
       var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       loadJson(mesh);
   });
    function loadJson(mesh){
        groupB.add(mesh);
    }

scene.add( groupB );
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : put value as option1 and option2 to respective radio button and check value in click handler to load respective group.

HTML:

```
<input id="option1" type="radio" name="options" value="option1" checked="checked"/>
<input id="option2" type="radio" name="options" value="option2" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    //load group for already selected radio button
    var checkedRadioVal = $('input[name="options"]:checked').val();
    if(checkedRadioVal == "option1")
    {
        //call code to load group A
    }
    else  if(checkedRadioVal == "option2")
    {
       //call code to load group B
    }

    //click handler for radio button
    $('input[name="options"]').click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "option1")
        {
          //call code to load group A
        }
        else  if(value == "option2")
        {
          //call code to load group B
        }
    });
 });
```